# Trying to install sympy on Debian

Tags: sympy, python-3.8

I want to install sympy on Debian but when I write pip3 install sympy this error ocurred and I don't know why or what can I do for install sympy.

```
    Collecting sympy
    Using cached sympy-1.7-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 MB)
    Collecting mpmath>=0.19
    Using cached mpmath-1.1.0.tar.gz (512 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =    '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hxmtj55j/mpmath_c9b7987c1db040b698a770d3b6728d02/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-hxmtj55j/mpmath_c9b7987c1db040b698a770d3b6728d02/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-mdx_oaij
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-hxmtj55j/mpmath_c9b7987c1db040b698a770d3b6728d02/
   Complete output (11 lines):
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
   from setuptools.dist import Distribution
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 32, in <module>
   from setuptools import windows_support
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
   import ctypes
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
   ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for    full command output.
```

Comment: You need to install the `python3-dev` package.